# Opening 7Zip filez in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, 7zip, compression

How do I open a 7zip file in Python using plzma? I'd like to write a process to take a directory full of 7zip files, pull all the file names, open one file into memory (at a time), store the archive (name.7zip) name, and take the compressed file into memory to be processed.

Thank you!

Comment: from python 3.3+, you can use the built-in `lzma` library

Comment: Sorry, using python 2.7. Will edit.

Comment: there appears to be no real way to read and write `.7z` files. For purely reading you can use `py7zlib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive It's a python wrapper for libarchive library so you must have the library installed. Another possible wrapper is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive-c